# Updating a postgresql column with a random element from a list of strings

Tags: postgresql, random, sql-update

I would like to randomly update the registered_party column of each row in my table named table_name with a string from this list ['republican', 'democrat']. I am running into a syntax error. How can I fix the query so that it achieves the goal.

```
 Update table_name set registered_party =
  select from (unnest(ARRAY['republican','democrat'])
   FROM generate_series(1, 10)
  ORDER BY random() )
  LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Please use this political generated info responsibly. We have enough problems in politics without tech enabling/weaponizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: This doesn't use your list in an unnest block, so if you need more than these values, it won't work as is.

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN random() > 0.5 THEN 'republican' ELSE 'democrat' END AS party
FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS g(i)
```

Outputs something like the following:

```
 party
------------
 democrat
 republican
 republican
 democrat
 democrat
 democrat
 republican
 republican
 democrat
 republican
```

Your final update statement would look like this.

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET registered_party = (
  SELECT CASE WHEN random() > 0.5 THEN 'republican' ELSE 'democrat' END
  WHERE table_name.id = table_name.id
);
```

You need the `WHERE` clause on the subselect. Otherwise it will choose either 'democrat' or 'republican', and then set every entry in the table to that one party. You want each row to be either-or.